# Meteor.js 1.0: How do I return an _id outside of ObjectId using this._id?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, nitrousio

I'm going through the simple tutorial on the site [Meteortips.com](http://meteortips.com/book/sessions/) to learn about session variables, but I'm having trouble retrieving the object id.

When I follow the instructions word for word, I end up with this code:

```
Template.leaderboard.events({
    "click .player": function(){
      var playerId = this._id;
      Session.set("selectedPlayer", playerId);
      console.log(playerId)
    }
  })
```

When I log `playerId`, according to the tutorial, I am supposed to get the `id` in the form: `546d2e4e1c9a86a33e37005d`, but instead, I get it in the form:

```
LocalCollection._ObjectID 
  {_str: "546d2e531c9a86a33e37005e", 
    toString: function, 
    equals: function, 
    clone: function, 
    typeName: function…}
```

I then thought to try using `toString()`, which ended up making the equivalency test work in a later part of the tutorial (so it solved the problem), but it still returned `ObjectID("546d2e461c9a86a33e37005c")` when I was expecting the `id` without the `ObjectID()` thing wrapped around it.

How can I get the `id` without all the extra stuff?

## Edit

It might be worth noting that I did all of this on a Chromebook using Nitrous.io. I coped the code from Nitrous.io into Meteorpad [here](http://meteorpad.com/pad/RnL255jMpdwtBWW8h/Id%20Test%20for%20Stackoverflow) and it works like it's supposed to.

The only way I was able to get the `id` I wanted while in Nitrous.io was by using `this._id._str` instead of just `this._id`. I still have no idea why that is... But that's what happened.

Comment: When you insert the player into the collection, are you setting the `_id` yourself or are you letting the server do that for you?

Comment: I'm letting the server set it.

Comment: This shouldnt happen. Can you reproduce it in a [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/)?

Comment: lol. nice edit. I warned you about nitrous.io!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't give a value for **_id** when inserting an item to your Mongo db directly, it will use a special [ObjectID](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) for **_id**. If you insert an item using Meteor Collection it will use a random 17 character string by default for **_id**. Just add data using Meteor collections or manually set the _id to a random 17 character string when you add data.